# Only register a user's tap every 3 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How would you make it so that the app only registers the user's tap ever 3 seconds. For example: after the user taps the screen the app will not register or recognize any more taps until 3 seconds has gone by, and then repeat this. This would be to stop spamming it by tapping as fast as possible. I read up on gesture recognizer but I didn't see how I could use it.

Comment: you mean you want to do like if user tap screen once and then user can not  do anything for 3 seconds. right?

Comment: Yes, I just don't want them tapping the screen as much as possible since it will mess up the game.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I am. The code below by trojanfoe gives me no errors but for some reason does not work when the app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the last time the user tapped the screen with a property:

```
@interface GameScene()

@property NSTimeInterval lastTouch;

@end
```

and compare the time difference between the current and last tap by

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    // Check time since the last touch event
    if (touch.timestamp-_lastTouch >= 3) {
        // Allow touch
        NSLog(@"greater than or equal to 3 seconds");
    }
    else {
        // Ignore touch
        NSLog(@"Seconds since last touch %g",touch.timestamp-_lastTouch);
    }
    // Store timestamp
    _lastTouch = touch.timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Just like with trojanfoe's code there were no errors but when the app was built it did not work... I tried messing around with the code and it still doesn't work in the app. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Comment out code that adds gesture recognizers if you have any. If it still doesn't work, try creating a new SpriteKit project and replace the `touchesBegan` with the above code.

Comment: Seems to be working, but you can still tap as much as you want in the app. In the console is says the seconds since last touch, but still doesn't stop the user's tap from working.

Comment: When I was testing the code, I noticed the 3 seconds is a long time to wait to tap again. So I added the `else` statement to log the elapsed time since the last tap. You can use that to adjust the allowable time between taps that is appropriate for your app. In the end, you should delete the `else` statement and only process taps in the `if` condition is `true`.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case it is perfect! Do you happen to know how to have the user's tap not register in the app (I have it so that when the user taps the screen my sprite moves across the screen) unless 3 seconds has gone by?

Comment: Is it possible for you add the code that moves the sprite into the `if` statement above?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the last time the user tapped the button, using an instance variable:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
{
    NSTimeInterval _lastTap;
}
@end
```

and in the action method, ignore anything less than 3 seconds ago:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    if (_lastTap > 0.0 && now - _lastTap < 3.0)
        return;
    _lastTap = now;
    // Handle tap
}
```

Comment: After putting in the code I have received no errors but when I run the app it doesn't seem to work. I can't find anything wrong with the code and I have even tried repositioning where the code is with the other code, very strange. Thank you anyways!